# Connecting a computer to analog cable

Tags: tv, analog

I have a PC with all the usual outputs and a couple of TVs in the house with inputs to connect to a computer. Now, what i would like to do is get rid of cable TV and using the input into the splitters in the basement,( ie. where the input cable from outside actually feeds the system ) have the computer become the "Cable supplier" ( so to speak ) and have the output ( via some sort of box ) from the computer, convert what is on my monitor into an RF signal that is then fed into the cables in my house and ultimately to each TV / room .

I don't know if there is such an item but would welcome any thoughts you might have on such a set up. I am not into HD or the like, so the picture quality needs only to be watchable, not HD. I don't want to have to set up separate cables to feed the audio on each TV.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an [RF modulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF_modulator).  Assuming you can get a composite signal out of your video card, you would hook that and your audio (using a 3.5mm to stereo RCA splitter) to the modulator, pass that output through a cable TV amplifier (although that might not be needed) and then into your home cable wiring.  Honestly, the signal isn't going to look very good.  You're much better off hooking one of your computers up to a single TV using composite or component cables.

Answer (score 0):

A TV RV modulator such as [this](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103095#tabsetBasic) would be a start to do what you want.  However, the computer would only be feeding one "channel" into the system and all the TVs would be dependent on what the computer was pushing up the cable.  As long as you're good with using the computer to select your feed, and don't need to watch different shows on different TVs, than this should work for you.